# Azure Storage Table ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync Call Error in Extension Method

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

The below extension method won't compile in my ASP.NET Core project and Visual Studio highlights the method ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync as the problem. The error (below the code) is citing a method signature I don't want. I want this one [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn434804.aspx).

```
internal static class CloudTableExtensions
{
        public static async Task<IList<DynamicTableEntity>> ExecuteQueryAsync(this CloudTable table,
            TableQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var items = new List<DynamicTableEntity>();
        TableContinuationToken token = null;
        do
        {
            var seg = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token, cancellationToken);

            token = seg.ContinuationToken;
            items.AddRange(seg);


        } while (token != null && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested 
             && (query.TakeCount == null || items.Count < query.TakeCount.Value));


        return items;
    }
}
```

**The error is:**
`Error  CS0411  The type arguments for method 'CloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T, TResult>(TableQuery<T>, EntityResolver<TResult>, TableContinuationToken)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: Are you using the latest release of .net core ? which version of windowsazure.storage are you using ?

Comment: Yes I am using ASP.NET Core 1.0.0 and WindowsAzure.Storage 7.1.3-Preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WindowsAzure.Storage 7.1.3-Preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/7.1.3-preview) nuget package for ASP.NET Core 1.0.0
does not contains an `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` function with this signature.
Maybe you should create an issue for this on the [github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net).

Otherwise, if you need to pass the cancellation token, you can use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn434901.aspx):

```
internal static class CloudTableExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IList<DynamicTableEntity>> ExecuteQueryAsync(this CloudTable table,
        TableQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var items = new List<DynamicTableEntity>();
        TableContinuationToken token = null;
        do
        {
            var seg =
                await
                    table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token, new TableRequestOptions(), new OperationContext(),
                        cancellationToken);

            token = seg.ContinuationToken;
            items.AddRange(seg);


        } while (token != null && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested
                 && (query.TakeCount == null || items.Count < query.TakeCount.Value));


        return items;
    }
}
```